# parent div centered but it stick in the top of page

Tags: html, sass

I have a parent div I want to center "quote-box":

```html
<div class="warpper">
<div id="quote-box">
  <h2 id="text">ggggg</h2>
  <p id="autor"></p>
  <button id="new-quote">
    <a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote">new qoute</a>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code centers the parent, but it centers at the top:

```css
.warpper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

#quote-box{
  width:40%;
  padding:10vw;
  background-color:gray;
  border-radius:2vw;
  text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Comment: suggestion : add a css language identifier to highlight the code and make it better to read

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the wrapper to span over the whole viewport. By default, the height of a container depends on the content. Therefore you can't see the vertical centering. `100vh` sets the container height to 100% of the visible viewport so you can see centering of the flexbox.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.warpper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#quote-box{
  width:40%;
  padding:10vw;
  background-color:gray;
  border-radius:2vw;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="warpper">
<div id="quote-box">
  <h2 id="text">ggggg</h2>
  <p id="autor"></p>
  <button id="new-quote">
    <a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote">new qoute</a>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```